Using Boost.Hana library with standard C++20 or higher?
wondering if anyone has used Boost.Hana with more recent versions of standard C++? Are there any still-valid use cases to apply Boost.Hana e.g. since C++20 template metaprogramming seem to have some useful constructs like 'concepts' which may invalidate the usage of more verbose Hana constructs?
It's a general exploratory question as I'm learning meta programming in modern C++ (C++17 and higher) and trying to create a learning roadmap what else will I need after I cover features provided by standard C++... Boost.Hana appears to be promising but it seems to have been supported until C++14 version only.

Being "a C++14 library" usually means "works with C++14 and later, but doesn't compile with C++11". It is hardly ever "C++14 only". But, as you have noticed, the usefulness might decrease when new language features arrive so you can do the things without extra library support.

I'm struggling to come up with any Hana feature that might have become less relevant in c++20. You vaguely mention concepts, but I really don't see which "more verbose" Hana constructs would be "invalidated" by it. Perhaps you could start with supporting your claim that Hana be "supported until c++14 only".
